# How to restore shiny inputs if a disconnection happens?

Tags: r, shiny

I developed a data collection app in shiny that is going to be used on iPads. The app is deployed on shinyapps[dot]io. While testing, I found that if the iPad goes to sleep, the user is disconnected. All inputs are lost and the user needs to start over. The iPad goes to sleep while the users pay attention to the experiment and are not actively using the app. I have made sure that the app does not time out by changing the settings on shinyapps[dot]io.

This [article](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/improve/reconnecting/) on the official shiny website suggests putting `session$allowReconnect(TRUE)` in the `server` to reconnect to a new session. I tried it but still lose the inputs upon disconnection. Perhaps because this requires a shiny server.

1. Is the only solution to this is to not let iPad sleep?
2. Can the inputs be cached somehow so that a user gets back to their inputs after the disconnection?
3. Should I continuously save inputs in a database even without clicking a
   save button (I already do this but upon clicking a save button), and
   then restore the inputs from the database when a user refreshes the disconnected page?
   I am afraid that would slow down the app significantly.